# Updating the ~/.bashrc file for a script

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc

I am developing a script that will configure and setup an ubuntu-desktop environment. One of the changes it makes is appending functions and other things to the `~/.bashrc` file. Later in the script, I need to call one of the functions added to `~/.bashrc` but I get the `command not found` error. Here is an example script:

```
# t.sh
#!/bin/bash

text='test-func() { echo It works!; }'
echo "$text" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
test-func

echo checkpoint
```

Output:

```
./t.sh: line 10: test-func: command not found
checkpoint
```

I assumed sourcing `~/.bashrc` would update the shell allowing me to call `test-func` but it does not. Googling around I found `exec bash` to replace `source ~/.bashrc`.

New Output:

```
./t.sh: line 10: test-func: command not found
```

From my understanding of `exec`, it just creates a new shell cutting the script off; therefore "checkpoint" is never printed out.

**How can I update `~/.bashrc` and run the updates in the same script?**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: and what if you try a random file.txt instead of .bashrc ?

Comment: @Serg What do you mean by use a text file? The purpose of using `~/.bashrc` is to be able to call the function.

Comment: Have you tried giving the full path instead of the ~/ ?

Comment: @Nelson see Malte's answer. My suspicion was exactly what he describes - `~/.bashrc` has a way of detecting if the shell is running non-interactively ( i.e. when you are running a script ) and will quit without executing your definitions ( that's what sourcing a file does - it "executes" the definitions ). You will need to have a separate file for defining your functions, if you want them to be sourced both from within `~/.bashrc` AND from a script

Comment: I don't think that's the issue as this scenario has also played out the same using `$HOME` instead of `~` but I tested it anyways and it does the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, your `.bashrc` does get sourced. However, `.bashrc` is intended to be read by interactive shells. A shell that runs a script is not interactive.

In Ubuntu, `.bashrc` checks that the shell sourcing it is interactive, and otherwise stops execution. You should find this line towards the beginning:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

This causes your script to stop sourcing the file before it reads your function.

You can simply attach your function to another file than `.bashrc` and it should work fine. If you insist on using `.bashrc`, you could simply set the variable `PS1` to some dummy value in your script before sourcing `.bashrc`.

Comment: In fact, it's a frequent practice to have separate files for aliases and function definitions.  Good answer

Comment: I do insist on using `~/.bashrc` because I wish to intend on using the functions in the terminal as well as later in the mentioned script. I looked through as well as searched the `~/.bashrc` file and that line of code is not there. Just to be sure I set `PS1=false` at the very top of the file. This had no effect.

Comment: @Nelson Can you post your `.bashrc` to Pastebin?

Comment: To move my aliases and functions to a separate file, would I just source the separate file in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Nelson  Well, again, as I mentioned - frequent practice is to source `~/.bash_functions` file from both within a script when you need and from `~/.bashrc` That way you can simply update that file, and it will work for both interactive and non-interactive sessions

Comment: I agree with Serg, a separate file is a much cleaner way of handling things than tricking a non-interactive shell into sourcing your `.bashrc`. :-)

Comment: Thank you @MalteSkoruppa and @Serg for your very helpful input! I have moved all of my `.bashrc` additions to a separate file out of OCD with code and file neatness, and it solves my problem. I can create, source, then call the `.bash_functions` file in the same script.